# Trying to install service programatically from VB.Net application - Calls to SC.exe fail

Tags: vb.net, service, sc.exe

I have a config program and a bunch of services that run per configured device.  In my config program when a device to monitor is added I create a service with a ID using something like this:

```
Dim appPath As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
Dim servicePath As String = appPath & "\MyService.exe"
Dim serviceName As String = "MyService-" & DeviceID
Dim createCommand As String = "sc.exe create " & serviceName & " binpath= " & Chr(34) & servicePath & " " & mySiteID & Chr(34) & " type= share start= demand"
Process.Start(createCommand)
```

So when it all comes together it looks something like this:

```
sc create MyService-253 binpath= "C:\Some Path\Project Name\MyService.exe 253" type= share start= demand
```

Problem is the service isn't being created.  The process command is throwing a "The system cannot find the file specified".

The program (and VS) are running as a admin.  Also copying and pasting the contents of the createCommand variable DOES work to correctly create the service.  So if I manually run the same command that should be run it creates the service and the service works correctly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure about the value of binpath? Isn't that device id supposed to be escaped?

Comment: I tried it with the escaping quotes ( \") and it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a full commandline to `Process.Start` like that. If you had read the documentation for that method then you would know that you need to pass the file path and the commandline arguments separately, e.g.

```vb
Dim appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
Dim servicePath = Path.Combine(appPath, "MyService.exe")
Dim serviceName = "MyService-" & DeviceID
Dim fileName = "sc.exe"
Dim arguments = $"create {serviceName} binpath= ""{servicePath} {mySiteID}"" type= share start= demand"
Process.Start(fileName, arguments)
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank-you.